# Given the two statements "Some Analysts are fools" and "Some fools are rich", what else can be determined?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

an interesting question as below:

The following statements are made:

- Some Analysts are fools.
- Some fools are rich.

Which of the below statements are true?

A.  “Some Analysts are rich”

B.  “Some rich people are Analysts”

C.  “Some Analysts are rich” or “Some rich people are Analysts”

D.  Neither “Some Analysts are rich” and “Some rich people are Analysts”

E.  Both “Some Analysts are rich” and “Some rich people are Analysts”

This's how i see it: Some Analysts are fools, which are rich. = Some Analysts are rich. Reverse it and read it from the end of sentence to beginning, I got "Some rich people are Analysts". So (E).

Seems **E** is the best answer. Do you agree? Or, there's no a definite answer?

Comment: No.  It's entirely possible that the only rich Fools are non-Analysts.

Comment: *None* of them follow from the original two statements!

Comment: (E) is certainly a non-sequitur. This does not necessarily mean that it's not the best answer.

Comment: See [Syllogism: Syllogistic fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Syllogistic_fallacies).

Comment: Why do you believe that (E) is the best answer?

Comment: Note:  $D$ is poorly worded.  I can't tell if it means that neither of those two statements follows from the assumptions (which would make it a true statement) or if it means something else (not sure what else it could mean, but that "and" is confusing.  I think it should be a "nor".).

Comment: @Théophile, this's how i see it: Some Analysts are fools, which are rich. = Some Analysts are rich. Reverse it and read it from the end of sentence to beginning, I got "Some rich people are Analysts". So (E).

Comment: @MarkK: But you don't know that every fool is rich -- only that _some_ fools are rich, and the fools who are rich are not necessarily the same fools that are analysts.

Comment: @MarkK Thanks for explaining. Please add your thoughts to the problem itself; otherwise, it is likely to be downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the formulas "some $X$ are $Y$" and "some $Y$ are $X$" are equivalent: they are both a way of stating that $X \cap Y \neq \emptyset$.

With this in mind, let us use $A,F,R$ for the sets of analysts, fools, and rich people. We know that:

$$A \cap F \neq \emptyset\\
F \cap R \neq \emptyset$$

The question asks which of these is true:

> A. $A \cap R \neq \emptyset$
>   B. $R \cap A \neq \emptyset$
>   C. $A \cap R \neq \emptyset$ or $R \cap A \neq \emptyset$
>   D. $A \cap R = \emptyset$ and $R \cap A = \emptyset$
>   E. $A \cap R \neq \emptyset$ and $R \cap A \neq \emptyset$

Most of these are redundant; we can simplify the question to the following.

> A,B,C,E. $A \cap R \neq \emptyset$
>   D. $A \cap R = \emptyset$

But we can't conclude that either of these is true, since we don't know anything about $A \cap R$.

Comment: this's marvelous! thank you for the knowledge and sharing.

Comment: @MarkK You're welcome!